# Change Unity's spell check language

Tags: 16.04, language-support, spell-checking

I am using English(US) as "display language for menus and messages" and for keyboard (easier for typing and getting help online).
However I would like the system wide spell checking to be French because I usually write in French.

Is there a way to do this on Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Thank you

Comment: Changing the display language to French would help. Would that be an option for you?

Comment: Hum, I would rather stay with english as my display langage, but you're right, I might not have any other option !

Comment: There may be another option - please see the answer I wrote.

Comment: Please note that there are application specific settings of language for spell checking, and there is no system wide spell checking setting which would override such settings. So I think it would help if you could specify a few applications where the 'issue' applies.

Answer (score 0):

One thing worth trying, if you want to keep English as display language, is to open `~/.profile` for editing and add this line:

```
export LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried what you hinted with no success.

Comment: @LouisM: Did you relogin after having added that line? (I should have mentioned that.)